# Facing syntactical problems while writing Inline bash Command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

Had this issue while working with inline bash command and this thing got me really confused.
So, say I declare a shell variable temp and give it a value:

`> temp='hello'`

and now to echo this result in UPPER CASE using inline commands I write

```
 bash -c "echo ${temp^^}"
 HELLO
```

which is totally fine and I'm okay with it.
Now while studying this topic I came across this line,
"Whenever we put code in a string (such as in the case of passing it in as an argument),
the code should be single-quoted."

And this line is helpful as it solves the ambiguity can be caused by multiple double quotes.

So, following this I wrote the code as follows:

```
bash -c 'echo "${temp^^}"'
```

Which gave me no output. I tried to do a verbose command on this one which gave me this:

```
bash -cv 'echo "${temp^^}"'
echo "${temp^^}"
```

Can somebody explain why the result is not getting displayed as HELLO, would really appreciate it.

Comment: It kinda does, but none of the explanations answered why this was happening? I want to know the reason this happens. Thanks for the remedy for this though :)

Comment: here's another thing that happened. When I try to display the value of positional parameters the result displayed is as expected.example                                 bash -c 'echo "1: $1, 2: $2, 4: $4"' -- 'New First Argument' Second Third 'Fourth Argument'                 which gives the result: 1: New First Argument, 2: Second, 4: Fourth Argument

Comment: Please note the above referenced answer related to using variables inside single quotes.  Since you're starting a new shell, you could export the variable first so that the variable is available in the newly-created process.

Comment: @AndyDalton So when we use inline bash, we're essentially carrying out our code in a separate shell, is that right ?

Comment: Try running `export temp` ;)

Comment: yup, I got it :)